# Space allocation for Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, partition, hard-disk

I am going to install `Linux Mint 19.1`. My RAM is 4 GB and Hard Drive is 500 GB. In this case how much space should I allocate for `swap`,'/','/home' and 'EFI' partitions ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't expect one correct answer, sine this is highly opinion-based. What will this system be used for?

Comment: Thanks @StrabagISS_Krall. I would like to use it as Desktop for Web Development purpose.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to split the partitions this way.  Swap *files* are very common these days and avoid the need for a dedicated partition.  You don't *need* to have `/home` on a different partition to `/`.  That would give you the most flexibility.  Beyond that it's just about guessing how much you will need for `/`. And how much you can spare to lose from `/home`.  50GB isn't a bad start for `/`.  Most likely too big.